# Intialized vector in AUC function out of bounds

Tags: r, data-mining, auc

I am trying to use cross validation with a decision tree using AUC. These are the functions that I am using:

```r
.cvFolds <- function(Y, V) {  
  Y0 <- split(sample(which(Y == 0)), rep(1:V, length = length(which(Y == 0))))
  Y1 <- split(sample(which(Y == 1)), rep(1:V, length = length(which(Y == 1))))
  folds <- vector("list", length = V)
  for (v in seq(V)) folds[[v]] <- c(Y0[[v]], Y1[[v]])   
  return(folds)
}

.doFit <- function(V, folds, train) {
  set.seed(v)
  ycol <- which(names(train) == y)
  params <- list(x     = train[-folds[[V]], -ycol],
                 y     = as.factor(train[-folds[[V]], ycol]),
                 xtest = train[folds[[V]], -ycol])
  fit <- do.call(randomForest, params)
  pred <- fit$test$votes[, 2]
  return(pred)
}
```

This is the function to calculate probabilities:

```r
iid_example <- function(train, y = "V1", V = 10, seed = 1) {
  set.seed(seed)
  folds <- .cvFolds(Y = train[, c(y)], V = V)
  
  # Generate CV predicted values
  cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
  registerDoParallel(cl)
  predictions <- foreach(v = 1:V, .combine = "c", 
    .packages = c("randomForest")) %dopar% .doFit(v, folds, train)
  stopCluster(cl)
  predictions[unlist(folds)] <- predictions

  # Get CV AUC
  runtime <- system.time(res <- ci.cvAUC(predictions = predictions, 
                                         labels = train[, c(y)],
                                         folds = folds, 
                                         confidence = 0.95))
  print(runtime)
  return(res)
}
```

The actual function call:

```r
res <- iid_example(train = datos, y = "V1", V = 10, seed = 1)
```

When I try to run it, I get the following error:

> Y0[[v]] out of bounds

I am trying to adjust the parameterization of the function, but I do not understand why it is out of boundaries. Thanks for your help

Comment: @slamballais Thank you for your help. I do still have a problem with this functions, but now is with the .doFit function. It says: ```Error in .doFit(v, folds, train) : 
  task 1 failed - "could not find function ".doFit""
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In split.default(sample(which(Y == 2)), rep(1:V, length = length(which(Y ==  :
  data length is not a multiple of split variable
2: In split.default(sample(which(Y == 2)), rep(1:V, length = length(which(Y ==  :
 
 Error in .doFit(v, folds, train) : 
  task 1 failed - "could not find function ".doFit"" ```

Comment: After I modified some parameters that were undefined, I still get the error message that says: Error in .doFit(v, folds, train) : 
  task 1 failed - "could not find function ".doFit""

Comment: I have a question: The error I get from the .doFit function can be caused by a data.frame data type and a labelled numeric response variable?

Comment: This is the traceback:  `4.
stop(simpleError(msg, call = expr)) 
3.
e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) 
2.
foreach(v = 1:V, .combine = "c", .packages = c("randomForest")) %dopar% 
    .doFit(V, folds, train) 
1.
iid_example(train = datos, y = "pobreza", V = 10, seed = 1) `